# Use whois to get country from IP address in Perl

Tags: perl, ip, country, whois

how can I get country from IP address in Perl? I have to use whois to do it.
I know, that to take country I can use:

```
$test = `whois $ip |grep -i country`;
```

But it returns me `"Country:           DE"`. I need just "DE".

Comment: The Country you're seeing isn't necessarily the "country from IP address". You should look into something like http://search.cpan.org/~maxmind/Geo-IP-1.45/lib/Geo/IP.pm instead.

Comment: But I had to use whois :P In school my task is to use "whois" and get country from this.

Comment: Do not escape to the shell to do that, you have many whois libraries in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $country = `whois $ip | grep -Po '^Country:\s*\K.*';
chomp($country);
```

But seeing as the "P" in `-P` stands for "Perl", we might as well get rid of `grep`.

```
my $whois = `whois $ip`;
my ($country) = $whois =~ /^Country:\s*(.*)/m;
```

Answer (score 0):

I made it in little noob way, but it works xd

```
$test = `whois $_ |grep -i country`;
$rid = rindex($test, ":");
$b = substr("$test, $rid+1);
```

And now I have just "DE", "BR", "CN", "MX" etc :)